# VBA - dictionary running through a worksheet holding a key plus two related columns

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary

The idea here is that i am having a sheet with more than 80,000 rows and six different columns. what I care about is the 2 columns though. I want the vba to go through each row, get the source IP in column D and the last word in the message box in column F after this "->" symbol, an example of the word is "175.55.78.35:8545" because the numbers in between the dots vary i feel like the best way to separate the words is through " ". Then once it's done retrieving the values from all the rows, print the results in 3 columns on a new sheet.

NOTE that one IP address can be related with many different words.

What i am looking for, is the vba return the source IP in one column, the number of times that the IP was found in column D for one word to the next column, seperate it with a comma (if along with the comma it can go to the next line staying in the same cell, even better), then the number of times that it found a different a word etc. and lastly the next column have the word retrieved from column F which is related with the first count of the 2nd column, seperate that with a comma, then the second word being related again with the second count of the previous column and then go to the next row for the other IP and so forth.

[this is how the table looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDsz4.png)

For the code this is what i have. If the comments are removed, the following code only counts the times the source ip is found in the worksheet and prints the results in a different sheet.

```
Sub timesofattack2()

Dim data As Variant, key As Variant, dic As Object
Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    data = .Range("D8", .Range("D" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp)).Value
End With

For Each key In data
    dic(key) = dic(key) + 1
Next

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    .Range("A2").Resize(dic.count).Value = Application.Transpose(dic.Keys())
    .Range("B2").Resize(dic.count).Value = Application.Transpose(dic.Items())
End With

End Sub


 'Dim arrayofwords() As String 
'arrayofwords = Split( , " ")
'Dim word As String
'Dim i As Integer

'For i = LBound(arrayofwords) To UBound(arrayofwords)
 'If arrayofwords(i) = "->" Then
 'word = arrayofwords(i + 1)
'End If
```

Comment: Your sheet has 80k columns?  You mean *rows* right?

Comment: Would help to show a couple of example values from Col F and what the last "word" is from each: difficult to interpret that from your screenshot

Comment: re: *'the last word in the message box in column F'* - so I guess you either have no data in one of the A:E columns or *'five different columns'* is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Try concatenating the IP and the tail end of the comment into a unque key using a delimiter that is unlikely to be in either value. The concatenated values can easily be split later.

```
Sub timesofattack2()

    Dim data As Variant, dic As Object, k As Long, ks As String

    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        data = .Range(.Cells(8, "D"), .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2)).Value2
    End With

    For k = LBound(data, 1) To UBound(data, 1)
        ks = Join(Array(data(k, 1), Split(data(k, 3) & "->", "->")(1)), ChrW(8203))
        dic(ks) = dic(ks) + 1
    Next

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
        .Range("A2").Resize(dic.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(dic.Keys)
        .Range("C2").Resize(dic.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(dic.Items)
        .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).TextToColumns _
            Destination:=.Cells(2, "A"), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
            Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar:=ChrW(8203), _
            ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1))
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the work, but it seems like with this code some source ips end up missing and not all the destination ips which are related to the source ips get calculated. Again thank you so much for you work though